# Image not fill width screen

Tags: wordpress, image, browser, width, fullscreen

Image width of my blog like this:

[image]

And I want them look like this:

[image]

I mean I want images width to fill the browser.

Comment: I think its about parent's padding. the box that is parent has padding . you should add  (padding:0px;)  to parent of these boxes

Comment: To add on what @eli said, if removing the passing from the parent element is not possible you could use negative margin, example: margin: 0 -15px; this is assuming that the parent padding is 15px

Comment: Iam not expert please give me steps how to solve this